# What is the significance of connect role in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

What is the purpose of connect role in oracle.

```
select * from role_sys_privs where role='CONNECT';          

ROLE       PRIVILEGE        ADMIN_OPTION
CONNECT    CREATE SESSION   NO
```

So based on the above information it is used to create session.

But i can find users who don't have the role of CONNECT but can still access the database.
So what is this CREATE SESSION about? and what can it do? is it necessary for all the users?

Comment: `create session` simply gives the user the ability to connect to the database. That's all, nothing more to it. Those users you mention probably have the `create session` privilege granted directly (or a different role) but not through the role `connect`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Database Security Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/guidelines.htm#DBSEG509), the `CONNECT ROLE` was changed in Oracle Database 10.2:

> The CONNECT role was originally established a special set of privileges.
>
> These privileges were as follows:
>
> ALTER SESSION
>
> CREATE SESSION
>
> CREATE CLUSTER
>
> CREATE SYNONYM
>
> CREATE DATABASE LINK
>
> CREATE TABLE
>
> CREATE SEQUENCE
>
> CREATE VIEW
>
> Beginning in Oracle Database 10g Release 2, the CONNECT role has only the CREATE SESSION privilege, all other privileges are removed.